# Определение типа(difference_type) разности итераторов для некоторой последовательности

Tags: c++

По каким соображениям можно определить тип разности итераторов для **красно_черного дерева** или же контейнера, представлением которого является красно_черное дерево?

Пример класса:

```
template <typename T>
class Red_Black_tree {
    enum  nodeColor { BLACK, RED };
    struct Node{
        struct Node_* left{ nullptr };
        struct Node_* right{ nullptr };
        struct Node_* parent{nullptr};
        nodeColor color{ BLACK };
        T data{};       
    };  
    Node* root; 
public:
    struct iterator {
        //как определить?
        using difference_type = //что?

        //... 
    };
    //кое что из интерфейса
    void rotateLeft(Node*);
    void rotateRight(Node*);
    void insertFixup(Node*);
    Node* insertNode(const T&);
    Node* findNode(const T&);
    //конструкторы, деструктор и т.д.
};
```

Comment: если не разбираться и сжульничать, то можно посмотреть, что использует `std::set`... скорей всего там `std::ptrdiff_t`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определите сначала, какой беззнаковый тип вы будете использовать для описания *количества* итерируемых узлов в вашем дереве, т.е. `size_type`. Тип `difference_type` должен быть знаковым типом, который хотя бы на один бит шире.

В реальности вы, возможно, столкнетесь с тем, что такого типа "на один бит шире" либо не существует, либо его использование неоправданно с точки зрения производительности. В такой ситуации иметь смысл взять знаковый `difference_type` той же ширины, что и `size_type`, в расчете на то, что размер вашего дерева никогда не достигнет таких величин, при которых произойдет переполнение этого `difference_type` (или просто явно ограничив максимальный размер дерева).

Если у вас нет каких-то дополнительных специальных соображений, то очевидными кандидатами на роль `size_type` и `difference_type` являются `std::size_t` и `std::ptrdiff_t`.